# Initializing HashMap datatype in Android

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have to send the parameters to the server.
Below is the code, of how I am using `HashMap`.

I am getting error in this code, I tried declaring latitude and longitude as `double` and use `Double` in `Map`. If I do that I start getting an error in the other parameter which are of `String` type.

```
protected Map<String,Double,Double, String> getParams() {
    // Posting params to register url
    Map<String, Double, Double, String> params = new HashMap<String, Double, Double, String>();
    params.put("tag", "LocationUpdate");
    params.put("email", email);
    params.put("latitude", latitude);
    params.put("longitude", longitude );
    params.put("last_seen",last_seen );
    return params;
}
```

Comment: Well there's no such thing as a `Map<String,Double,Double, String>` - the `Map` type has two type parameters - one for the key, and one for the value. You're trying to specify four type arguments. How did you expect that to work?

Comment: Why is it Map<String, Double, Double, String> ???

Comment: why don't you add lat and long as `String` only.  just Map<String,String>

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this

```
 protected Map<String,String> getParams()
    {
        // Posting params to register url
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
        params.put("tag", "LocationUpdate");
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("latitude", String.valueOf(latitude));
        params.put("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude));
        params.put("last_seen",last_seen );
        return params;
    }
```

Because a Map is a key-value container. Since everything can be parsed to a String in this example, just get the String value of your doubles and when you need them again do something like this:

```
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(params.get("latitude));
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to look at [java map api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) before using.

`Map` had only two Generic Type Variables. So you can create `map` with only two type arguments.

`Map<String, Double> = new HashMap<String,Double>`

here your key is of type `String` and Value of type `Double`.